# Input string was not in a correct format EF6

Tags: c#, mysql, database, entity-framework, string-formatting

I am currently using EF6 and trying to implement a one-to-many relationship using code-first:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
}

public class Instruction
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Schedule Schedule { get; set; }
}
```

I am following convention 1 [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx).

In my method i first try to add an empty schedule:

```
public class ScheduleRepo  {
    public void SetSchedule()
    {
        Schedule schedule = new Schedule();
        using (UptrenderDbContext ctx = new UptrenderDbContext())
        {
            ctx.Schedules.Add(schedule);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}´
```

The method is called from a test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ScheduleRepoTest {

    private readonly ScheduleRepo repo = new ScheduleRepo();

    [Test]
    public void TestSetSchedule()
    {
        repo.SetSchedule();     
    }
}
```

My context looks like this:

```
    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class UptrenderDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Instruction> Instructions { get; set; } //Not used yet

        public UptrenderDbContext () {
            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UptrenderDbContext >());
        }
    }
```

When running the program i get the stack trace:

Stack trace:

```
    System.FormatException : Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToDouble(String value)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(CreateIndexOperation op)
   at MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(IEnumerable`1 migrationOperations, String providerManifestToken)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
   at Data.Repos.Impl.ScheduleRepo.SetSchedule() in C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\uptrender\Data\Repos\Impl\ScheduleRepo.cs:line 20
   at Data.Tests.ScheduleRepoTest.TestSetSchedule() in C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\uptrender\Data\Tests\ScheduleRepoTest.cs:line 21
```

I notice that if i remove `public Schedule Schedule{ get; set; }` from `Instruction` no exception is thrown and `schedule` is successfully added to the db.

I probably missed something very trivial here because im new to EF6.

Comment: A stack trace would help. It's not clear where the exception occurs (your code, EF code?).

Comment: What does the `scheduleEntity` look like?

Comment: @MarkC it just contains an Id

Comment: @GertArnold Added stack trace

Comment: Is there a typo in your example? you new up as "schedule" but add a "scheduleEntity" to the DbSet..  Regardless, the error is when it tries to create your DB so there looks to be a problem with your migrations config, possibly attempting to populate default records?  Given an existing DB there shouldn't be any issue inserting a simple entity like that. I'd be looking at code first config.

Comment: @StevePy yeah it was a typo, thx for noticing. You are probably right, Il'l take a look.

Comment: Since this happens in `MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator` it looks like a bug. You should report it as an issue.

Comment: @StevePy I do not have a migration config, i didn't think it was required since i just drop the db each time the context is create `Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<UptrenderDbContext >());`

Comment: The error seems to stem that the MySQL implementation for the schema generation is taking exception to the table creation. I personally do not use code-first and schema generation/migration at all with EF as I much prefer to manage my schema separately. From memory though it does create extra tables to store migration information that it inspects as schemas are updated. It's possible that it's stored instructions based on earlier entity structures that it is still consulting during DropCreate. Perhaps wipe those tables if present.

Comment: @StevePy I wiped the tables / dropped the db / reinstalled mysql and the driver. Still the same issue, i am leaning towards managing my schemas externally aswell.